Acrylic does not work properly. Start the APP before turning on the transparency effect
1.Start the app after turning off the transparency effect in Windows 11 settings.
After launching the app and then turning on the transparency effect from Windows settings, Acrylic will not work properly.
2.My project implements SystemBackdrop using
CreateSystemDispatcherQueueController
SystemBackdropConfiguration
DesktopAcrylicController
3.I found WinUI 3 Gallery of
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Window
    x:Class="YourProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:YourProject"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.SystemBackdrop>
        <DesktopAcrylicBackdrop />
    </Window.SystemBackdrop>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button x:Name="myButton" Click="myButton_Click">Click Me</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

Also according to the above steps, DesktopAcrylicBackdrop cannot work normally, but MIca and AcrylicInApp can work normally.

Version:
CppWinRT       2.0.240405.15
BuildTools     10.0.22621.3233
WindowsAppSDK  1.5.240428000


5.Is this a WinUI bug?
6.What can I do to solve this problem?

You should share some reproducing code/project somewhere, it's not possible to help with some text describing that something doesn't work. How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

It seems that you are toggling the Windows Transparency effects settings On/Off, an app with a Mica backdrop responds to the change, while an app with an Acrylic backdrop does not. I was able to reproduce this issue, and it seems difficult to find a workaround.

Could you please show a minimal, reproducible sample without private information? I believe it's easier to copy a minimal sample than to write one.


WinUI 3 programs created with the official version of the latest SDK and API above can be 100% reproduced
The above is the DesktopAcrylic provided by XAML. This is the simplest example.
Of course, refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/system-backdrop-controller code to achieve the same. @YangXiaoPo-MSFT


Thank you for the information. I also reproduced it using WinUI-Gallery. You may report it at https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues.
